# how to solve undefined relationship [users] in App\Models\Clients .. I am trying to list clients and a respective creator(User) of a client

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, one-to-many, database-normalization

I am trying to get a list of clients and their respective user who created a respective client... Please assist. I have done relationships I do not know what am missing ... I am new to laravel framework.

Thanks in advance!

Below is my Clients model : UPDATE

```
<?php

namespace app\Models;
use App\Models\Users;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Clients extends Model { 

    protected $table = 'Clients';
    protected $fillable = ['name','email'];
    protected $hidden = [];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Users::class,'user_id');
    }


}

?>
```

My Users model : UPDATE

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use App\Models\Clients;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illminate\Database\Auth\Authenticatable;

class Users extends Model implement Authenticatable{

    protected $table = 'Users';
    protected $fillable = ['name','email','password'];
    protected $hidden = [];

    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Clients::class, 'user_id');
    }
}

?>
```

My ClientsController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Clients;
use App\Models\Users;

class ClientsController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function index(){
         $clients = Clients::with('users')->get();  

        return response()->json([
        'msg'=>'successfully connected API to clients',
        'client'=>$clients->toArray()
            ],200
        );
```

my client migration :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateClientTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        //
         Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table)
         {
            $table->increments('id');          
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
        Schema::create('clients');
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to add the foreing key in the relationship since you didn't do the recommandations :) like this : `return $this->hasMany(Clients::class, 'user_id');` the same thing for the clinets Model : `return $this->belongsTo(Users::class, 'user_id');` !!

Comment: Still, I get same error ...@Maraboc

Comment: Can somebody help?

Comment: Your user model does not need to extend Model or implement Authenticatable, it should just extend Authenticatable. Also if you're using a plural name for your user model, you will need to configure this or authentication will not work.

Comment: My auth is working fine I just need to pull client array together with user array within Client json... Auth has nothing to do with this problem am facing ...

Comment: @Joe what's the use to tell me about auth...?

Comment: @NeoSono Why are you asking me this if you're sure that auth is working?

Comment: What does this have to do with normalization?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it some weeks ago @Joe & @Maraboc  thanks for your inputs ... I changed Clients to Client, then it works fine.